# Can Pyomo be linked with Google's GLOP or CP-SAT solvers?

Tags: solver, pyomo, or-tools, cp-sat

Pyomo can be linked with several solvers Open source and commercial ones.

I was wondering if Pyomo can be linked with Google's GLOP or CP-SAT solvers?

Comment: Please, see this [thread](https://groups.google.com/g/or-tools-discuss/c/CAxy-LNVTU8).